# Why are these buttons mis-aligned in a TableLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using a table layout to arrange some buttons. As long as I use the same font for all the labels they are properly aligned in each row.

For some buttons I'd like to use icons from a custom ttf font.
When I use such an icon, the button is placed slightly higher, like so:

[image: slight offset]

(This image is scaled up to make the the problem more evident.)

I took measurements - the buttons appear to be of same height, regardless of the used font.

Why are the buttons not aligned properly? 
Does anyone have a suggestion to get them aligned?

Thanks.

Following CommonsWare's advice (thanks for the quick replies!), I tried this:

```
final LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
row.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

This did not work. Will try the base alignment comment next.

Comment: Try `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"` on the `<TableRow>`.

Comment: Or try `android:baselineAligned="false"` (also on the `TableRow`).

Comment: Ok, `layout_gravity` did not have any effect, but the `baseAligned` property helped. Thanks @CommonsWare and @cygery. Would you like to put your comment into an answer, so that I can mark it as correct and change the status for this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following attribute to your `TableRow`:

```
android:baselineAligned="false"
```

By default, the button labels' base lines are vertically aligned which causes the offset you experience.